# Python colour / formatting not working in pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have the following python class taken from a question on here:

```
class color:
    PURPLE = '\033[95m'
    CYAN = '\033[96m'
    DARKCYAN = '\033[36m'
    BLUE = '\033[94m'
    GREEN = '\033[92m'
    YELLOW = '\033[93m'
    RED = '\033[91m'
    BOLD = '\033[1m'
    UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'
    END = '\033[0m'
```

If I run my python program normally I can use a line of code such as this:

```
print(color.BOLD + "Welcome to the game" + color.END)
```

It will print in bold and underlined just fine.

I am using the following code to get pyinstaller to make a onefile exe

```
pyinstaller -c --onefile main.py
```

Pyinstaller creates this file fine and I can run it but the same code nows prints:

`←[1m` & `←[0m` where `\033[1m` and `\033[0m` are.

The expected output is:

> Welcome to the game

Actual output when running pyinstaller exe file is:

> ←[1mWelcome to the game←[0m

Is there any way to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently found a way to apply color formatting in python:

```
import os
os.system('cls') # Clears the console screen
```

Put the rest of your code below and it will work normally. Tested it with PyInstaller and it works too.

Comment: actually just `os.system("")` (if you wanna fix it without clearing screen) works too its actually something with the default terminal window on windows be it for cmd or powershell its the same, it works without doing this however if you're using windows terminal or the vs code terminal

and since when you package your app with pyinstaller its probably opening the default cmd window it needs that weird hack